# Java array not staying initialized

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, initialization

I've got an array in an array and want to initialize it with a for each loop.

```
// class variable  
Tree[][] trees;

// in constructor

this.trees = new Tree[length][with];

// initialize
for (Tree[] tree : this.trees){
    for(Tree tree2 : tree){
    tree2 = new Tree();
    System.out.println(tree2);
    }
}

for (Tree[] tree : this.trees) {
    for (Tree tree2 : tree) {
    System.out.println(tree2);
    }
}
```

What happens is that the first println prints initialized trees, so they got initialized. I thought everything is ok. But when I try to use these trees, I get a nullpointerexception. So I tried to loop through the arrays again, and the second println gives me null for every tree. How can this be? What am I missing here? Thank you!

Edit: Oh I'm very sorry, It wasn't the main but the constructor method the loops are placed.

Comment: you can't use `this` in the `main` method, because `main` is `static`. Also, this code `tree2 = new Tree();` has no effect at all, because `tree2` is just a local variable in the loop. There is no way to initialize objects the way you want with a for each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the first loop:

`tree2 = new Tree();`

This line indeed creates instance of `Tree` but it stores it in local variable `tree2` instead of in element of array `this.trees`.

You should iterate over array using inexed for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < trees.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < trees[i].length; j++) {
        threes[i][j] = new Tree();
    }
}
```

The difference between lines `threes[i][j] = new Tree();` and `tree = new Tree();` is that first stores instance in element of array and the second stores it in single variable.

Java references are not C pointers. The assignment of objects is assignment of reference by value.

Answer (score 3):

`tree2` is a local variable (available in the scope the loop), you assign the newly created `Tree` instance to *that variable* not to your array. Next you print the contents of *that variable* so it seems to work...

Instead you need to explicitly store the instance into `trees`, like this:

```
for (int l = 0; l < length; l++){
  for(int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
    trees[l][h] = new Tree();
    System.out.println(trees[l][h]);
  }
}
```

As you can see, it stores the instance in the array and uses the *array* to print the value.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment above, this:

```
for (Tree[] tree : this.trees){
    for(Tree tree2 : tree){
    tree2 = new Tree(); // changes tha variable tree2, does not touch the array.
    System.out.println(tree2);
    }
}
```

has no effect. You need

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        trees[i][j] = new Tree(); // obviously changes the array content.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in this for loop

```
for(Tree tree2 : tree)
{
    tree2 = new Tree();
```

you are doing the assignment to the local reference variable `tree2`, where as `tree[i][j]` doesn't get assigned any value.